# MYSQL: select where

Tags: mysql

let's say I have the following Table:

```
 ID, Name  ,insurance , per_diem, net_salary, rr, rent, other_allowances 
 1, John     1000          0          2000     0    0         0
 2, Jim      1000          0          2000     0    0         0
 3, Steve    500           0          3000     0    0         0
 4, Tom      0             0          0        0    0         0
```

I run the following query

```
SELECT Sum((((((applicant.insurance + applicant.per_diem) +
                applicant.net_salary) + applicant.rr) + applicant.rent) +
                applicant.other_allowances)) As available_fund 
WHERE applicant.id = id;   
From applicant
```

I want to get something like sum for every person

Is it possible?

Comment: If you post the error you are getting, people might be able to help more quickly. In your example, the FROM ... clause should be before the WHERE clause... Also, the condition in the WHERE clause does not seem to make sense. Finally, you do not really need so many parentheses.

Comment: Minor formatting change in SQL portion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must use from first then use where

```
     SELECT Sum(applicant.insurance + applicant.per_diem + 
              applicant.net_salary + applicant.rr + applicant.rent + 
              applicant.other_allowances) As available_fund 
     From applicant 
     group by  applicant.id
```

it will give all employees sum but if you want to get some particulate employee then put `where` condition

```
 WHERE applicant.id = id
```

Comment: But the got the result for one record. not for all records

Comment: have you use with without where and with group by  ?

Comment: Hi it works but the result duplicated nested to get 4 records result  got 12 records.

Comment: what is the duplicate ??

Comment: I think you need group by with name like   group by  applicant.name

Comment: Accepted and appreciate you support.